# CANT CREATE OR DROP SYNONYM

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the problem. When I try to create private synonym with specific name that is required for my case (it should be exactly that name - no none else) - I got error message that synonym with that name alredy exists.

**Query:**

```
CREATE SYNONYM FZ223_PPA.PURCHASE FOR FZ223_PURCHASE.PURCHASE;
```

**Error:**

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE SYNONYM FZ223_PPA.PURCHASE FOR FZ223_PURCHASE.PURCHASE
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00955: имя уже задействовано для существующего объекта
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

But I could not found any synonym with that name in the schema i tried to create synonyn for. For example i tried the following query

```
select count(*) from dba_synonyms where owner = 'FZ223_PPA' and synonym_name = 'PURCHASE'
```

but it returns

[image]

The most disapointing thing is when I try to drop the schema with the same name - oracle gives me error and 'says' that the schema I try to drop not exists.

**Query:**

```
DROP SYNONYM FZ223_PPA.PURCHASE
```

**Error:**

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
DROP SYNONYM FZ223_PPA.PURCHASE
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01434: отменяемый личный синоним пользователя не существует
01434. 00000 -  "private synonym to be dropped does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I can't uderstand why and how to resolve it. I tried to find resolution of the problem, but found nothing. Help me please!

Comment: It's probably a table, view or something else: `select * from all_objects where owner = 'FZ223_PPA' and object_name = 'PURCHASE'`

Comment: Yes I found table with the same name! Thank you! So sad that Oracle DB namespace system makes no difference between objects with different types and with the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a view or table with schema-name and object name `foo.bar` already exists, you can't create a synonym `foo.bar`. That's all. And there's no point in using synonyms with the same schema and object name as the object they point to, really ...

*If* you actually need a synonym, you would need to create it in a different schema - whose owner you probably are not, and so the DBA must give you the privilege to create objects in a different schema.

Hope this helps ...

Comment: Actually I create synonym in different schema. I create synonym 'PURCHASE' in schema 'FZ223_PPA' for object 'PURCHASE' in another schema 'FZ223_PURCHASE'.

Comment: It could be that a PUBLIC synonym of the same name already exists. Can you search for it? or try to `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.PURCHASE` ?

Answer (score 0):

ORA-01434: private synonym to be dropped does not exist

SOLUTION :-

> DROP PUBLIC SYNONYM SYNONYM_NAME;